# How to reduce indentation level in given PHP code snippet

Tags: php, coding-style, refactoring

How to refactor this snippet of code, to reduce indentation level by one?
I just wonder is it possible in PHP to write this code in a diffrent way, with just one level of indentation.

The code:

```
private function isArrayMatchingCriteria(array $array) {
    foreach($array as $element) {
        if (! $this->isElementMatchingCriteria($element) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Please take into consideration, that:

- this code doesn't always iterate over all array elements - so combination of count + array_filter / array_map isn't the same
- it is easy to do by introducing a dedicated object attribute serving as a flag, but I'm looking for a way without introducing new attributes

Comment: I'm a bit confused; isn't this function only going to return either true or false to the first element of the array that is passed in? Why do you need foreach?

Comment: Is this really a problem that needs solving? Seems like the most straight forward solution. Having two levels of indentation is nothing to lose sleep over or post an SO question about IMO.

Comment: @Adunahay - no, it will not. It returns true only if the method 'isElementMatchingCriteria' returns true for every element of given array. False otherwise.

Comment: @deceze - Have I stated somewhere, that this is a serious problem of great importance? Can't I ask on SO a question like this? If I broke any rules, then I'll apologize and delete this post. If not, then what is your problem? Be helpful or move along...

Comment: @luigi I see that now, my mistake. If you are just looking to remove indentation, you could put the `return false` on the end of the previous line, like this: `if (!$this->isElementMatchingCriteria($element)) return false;`

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to remove indentation, you could use:

```
private function isArrayMatchingCriteria(array $array) {
    foreach($array as $element) {
        if (!$this->isElementMatchingCriteria($element)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I know I can do that, but it's not PSR-2 compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Use array_map, something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private function isElementMatchingCriteria( $element )
    {
        // DUMMY, replace with actual code
        if ( $element == "foo" || $element == "bar" ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } // end is Element Matching Criteria

    public function isArrayMatchingCriteria(array $array)
    {
        $results = array_map( array( $this, "isElementMatchingCriteria"), $array );
        $isMatch = true;
        foreach ( $results as $result ) {
            $isMatch = $isMatch && $result;
        } // end foreach
        return $isMatch;
    } // end function isArrayMatchingCriteria
} // end MyClass

$myClass = new MyClass();
$array = array( "foo", "bar", "baz" );
$result = $myClass->isArrayMatchingCriteria( $array );
print_r( $result );
```